# Available Memory Slots DL380G5

Tags: memory, hp-proliant

I have an HP ProLiant DL380 Generation 5 in a remote data center.  Is there any way that I can check remotely how many memory slots are occupied (and more importantly how many are available)?  The server is running SLES 11 in case that matters...

Comment: Do you have the iLO enabled or remote access?

Comment: If you have hptools installed, then try the command `hpasmcli -s "show dimm"`

Answer (score 2):

`lshw` may not be installed by default. However, `dmidecode` typically is.

`dmidecode -t 17` will show DIMM slot information.

Keep in mind that the ProLiant DL380 G5 has some specific [DIMM population rules](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12477_na/12477_na.html#Memory).

Answer (score 1):

> dmidecode

should also do the trick. It happens to be preinstalled very often, too.

Answer (score 0):

try the command :

```
lshw
```

It provides information about all your hardware, including what banks are free.

Comment: Also `dmidecode -t memory` (Not sure about SLES but RHEL doesn't have `lshw` in its main repo, only EPEL).